# For each day, subtract last time row from the first time row with Python

Tags: python, pandas, days, period

I have 5 minutes-interval meteorological df for many days. Some rows and days are missing. Index is datetime format.

```
DateTime               Data
2016-01-01 07:00:00     1
2016-01-01 10:30:00     2
2016-01-01 16:55:00     3

2016-03-25 09:25:00     4
2016-03-25 11:30:00     5
2016-03-25 13:35:00     6
2016-03-25 17:40:00     7 

2017-11-09 12:00:00     8
2017-11-09 13:05:00     9
2017-11-09 16:10:00    10
2017-11-09 18:15:00    11
2017-11-09 19:20:00    12
2017-11-09 20:25:00    13
```

I want to make a new_df of **daily** data with column **Data_diff**. Column Data_diff should contain the result of subtraction of the last data to the first data from each day.

The expected result is:

```
DateTime      Data_diff
2016-01-01    2
2016-03-25    3
2017-11-09    5
```

I have no idea what to do. Crossed in mind to use

```
new_df = df.diff()
```

but, it was not true for this case.

Edit: I also try the following

```
new_df = df.resample('D')['Data'].agg(['first','last'])
new_df['Data_diff'] = new_df['first'] - new_df['last']
```

but the result is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `resample` add all missing days filled by `NaN`s.

You can remove only these days by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
new_df = df.resample('D')['Data'].agg(['first','last']).dropna(how='all')
new_df['Data_diff'] =  new_df['last'] - new_df['first']
print (new_df)
            first  last  Data_diff
DateTime                          
2016-01-01    1.0   3.0        2.0
2016-03-25    4.0   7.0        3.0
2017-11-09    8.0  13.0        5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.groupby` together with `dt.day` and the apply the function you look for.

```
s = df.groupby(df['DateTime'].dt.day)['Data'].apply(lambda x: x.values[-1]-x.values[0])
print(s)
#           Data
# DateTime
# 1            2
# 9            5
# 25           3
```