# How to take difference between last value and first value of 30 min window, and keep other columns as well?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Parquet:
[Link to the sample dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ylq4tP9ck5bp8mla5GzwUZpRHtyOS62U/view?usp=sharing) 
CSV formatted:
[Link to the sample dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZlz-z_cwHwPIVRi0Q9OTA9cokKLx4Wg/view?usp=sharing) \

Updated dataset: [Link to new dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16r-hB3VhnlIG7XtZjtTynyyfqQETvqfm/view?usp=sharing)

The expected result should **have the result of difference between last value and first value of the 30 min sample window** (**From the sample data shown above**), that is:

```
    Item    Value   AgentStatus OriginalTimestamp   AgentTimeStamp
0   Channel1.Device1.Tag1   847 good    2023-07-28T13:09:00.0098328+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:00.0000000
1   Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:00.0408696+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:00.0000000
2   Channel1.Device1.Tag1   848 good    2023-07-28T13:09:05.0138770+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:05.0000000
3   Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:05.0454734+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:05.0000000
4   Channel1.Device1.Tag1   849 good    2023-07-28T13:09:10.0073605+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:10.0000000
5   Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:10.0379516+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:10.0000000
6   Channel1.Device1.Tag1   850 good    2023-07-28T13:09:15.0074263+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:15.0000000
7   Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:15.0387691+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:15.0000000
8   Channel1.Device1.Tag1   851 good    2023-07-28T13:09:20.0176840+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:20.0000000
9   Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:20.0329268+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:20.0000000
10  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   852 good    2023-07-28T13:09:25.0070191+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:25.0000000
11  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:25.0384699+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:25.0000000
12  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   853 good    2023-07-28T13:09:30.0109244+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:30.0000000
13  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:30.0417249+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:30.0000000
14  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   854 good    2023-07-28T13:09:35.0118763+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:35.0000000
15  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:35.0429050+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:35.0000000
16  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   855 good    2023-07-28T13:09:40.0027594+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:40.0000000
17  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:40.0340476+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:40.0000000
18  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   856 good    2023-07-28T13:09:45.0029277+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:45.0000000
19  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:45.0336946+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:45.0000000
20  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   857 good    2023-07-28T13:09:50.0153041+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:50.0000000
21  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:50.0459796+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:50.0000000
22  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   858 good    2023-07-28T13:09:55.0103680+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:55.0000000
23  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:55.0412343+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:55.0000000
24  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   859 good    2023-07-28T13:10:00.0095407+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:00.0000000
25  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:10:00.0395870+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:00.0000000
26  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   860 good    2023-07-28T13:10:05.0069727+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:05.0000000
27  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:10:05.0374699+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:05.0000000
28  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   861 good    2023-07-28T13:10:10.0113827+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:10.0000000
29  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:10:10.0431140+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:10.0000000
30  Channel1.Device1.Tag1   862 good    2023-07-28T13:10:15.0024582+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:15.0000000
31  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:10:15.0338704+09:00   2023-07-28T13:10:15.0000000
32  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:11:15.0338704+09:01   2023-07-28T13:11:15.0000000
33  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:12:15.0338704+09:02   2023-07-28T13:12:15.0000000
34  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:15:15.0338704+09:03   2023-07-28T13:15:15.0000000
35  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:20:15.0338704+09:04   2023-07-28T13:20:15.0000000
36  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:21:15.0338704+09:05   2023-07-28T13:21:15.0000000
37  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:22:15.0338704+09:06   2023-07-28T13:22:15.0000000
38  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:25:15.0338704+09:07   2023-07-28T13:25:15.0000000
39  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   878 bad 2023-07-28T13:30:15.0338704+09:08   2023-07-28T13:30:15.0000000
40  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:31:15.0338704+09:09   2023-07-28T13:31:15.0000000
```

Expected result/calculation:

After sampling within 30 mins, the result will contain data from these two items as shown:
[image]

- For each Item, Example: For **Channel1.Device1.Tag2**:
  **Last Value - First Value of the 30 minute windows**, i.e:

Last Row Value (878):

```
39  Channel1.Device1.Tag2   878 bad 2023-07-28T13:30:15.0338704+09:08   2023-07-28T13:30:15.0000000
```

First row value (0):

```
1   Channel1.Device1.Tag2   0   good    2023-07-28T13:09:00.0408696+09:00   2023-07-28T13:09:00.0000000
```

**Expected result/ dataframe:**

[image]

As seen, the Value 878 and 3 corresponds to Channel1.Device1.Tag2 and Channel1.Device1.Tag1, taking the difference between (last value - first value): (878 - 0) and (850-847), whereas other column values are retained.

**Update:**

The new dataset was run through the provided solution from mozway, and the results has a slight deviation (Instead of taking diff b/w 00:30:00 - 00:00:00) because of the duplicate value of timestamp against each item tag name. How to resolve this ? Or How to skip that duplicate value from the row.

I have to add this image, to explain:
[image]

Comment: What you want to do is unclear, please provide a **minimal** but complete example and the exact matching expected output (change the frequency if needed to keep the example short). (Also, the linked data is not following the show format).

Comment: @mozway I have edited the expected result. I hope its clear now. The result should contain difference of last and first value of the 30 min window, i.e (13:30 - 13:09) and the also has to keep the column names and that specific row values which had the timestamp 13.30 ( basically the last row values of that window)

Comment: @Nishad can you also make the example minimal and self-sufficient (no `...`)

Comment: @mozway I had put ... because there's many rows. Could you access this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OSi8QvBQ3b-4WWn73ypl4hn1Yp0ll2M4/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112221094992050432029&rtpof=true&sd=true

you can see the dataset.

Comment: I have access the link and the format is different (no time), anyway it is better to provide a self sufficient example directly in the question, links don't last forever and future readers won't be able to see the data. It should be easy to provide a small example.

Comment: Sorry, I have reuploaded the dataset link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10gE61lXPVLE_sz2m7nMLEd9zRmTSo1CA/view?usp=sharing

I'll also try to simplify it.

Comment: Hi @mozway, Could you look into the follow-up concern over the results please. I have added the update, and the issue over the comment.

Comment: @mozway, 
PLease could you look into it. Not sure why but its showing a small difference in the results with the new dataset. I have created  a new thread incase if you can't see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864982/how-to-take-difference-between-two-value-in-this-dataset-for-every-30-min-window

Answer (score 1):

What you want is unclear, maybe you can combine `groupby` and `resample`:

```
r = df.groupby('Item').resample('30T', on='AgentTimeStamp', origin='start', label='right')

out = (r.last()
        .assign(Value=lambda d: d[['Value']].sub(r[['Value']].first()))
        .reset_index('AgentTimeStamp')[df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
                       index                   Item  Value AgentStatus      AgentTimeStamp
Item                                                                                      
Channel1.Device1.Tag1      2  Channel1.Device1.Tag1      1        good 2023-07-28 13:39:00
Channel1.Device1.Tag2     39  Channel1.Device1.Tag2    878         bad 2023-07-28 13:39:00
```

Comment: Hi
What I want is similar to this but it should return the difference of values from last value and first value of the Channel1.Device1.Tag2 within 30 minute window. 
Somewhat similar to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615088/for-each-day-subtract-last-time-row-from-the-first-time-row-with-python

But with the row value of the Last Value used to substract.

Comment: @NishadNazar I believe this is what the code is doing, that's why it's important for you to provide a small but complete example **and** the exact matching expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope its clear now ? Please let me know

Comment: Thanks, but I see you only provided the output for one item and one window, can you provide the complete output?

Comment: Hi @mozway , I have provided the output for two items now. I don't have big dataset to show the complete output. 
I hope its better now. Please let me know

Comment: @NishadNazar I think my answer does what you described, your example seems incorrect, 878 is not the last value of the 30min window for Tag2, 0 is. How do you think my answer is not doing what you want?

Comment: Yes you are right, I was looking into it. Even for Tag1 there is no 30 min window, so the value is taken from AgentTimestamp: 2023-07-28T13:10:15.0000000 as its the last window right ? In the result, All the column values are retained, expect the AgentTimeStamp, both are 13:39:00. Is it possible to bring the values 2023-07-28T13:31:15.0000000 and 2023-07-28T13:10:15.0000000 for Tag2, and Tag1 respectively ?

Comment: Hi @mozway, 

Everything looks good. Thank you very much, 

Just one thing, can we retain AgentTimestamp as well alongwith other column values also. 13:39:00 doesn't look right. 

Also, I ran the code, How 'item' is displayed twice or Can it be eliminated ?

Comment: Hi, I applied the logic on a new dataset, but everytime it takes difference between last and first value within 20 minute window. For example: 3:20:00 - 3:00:00 and 3:50:00 - 3:30:00.. I haven't changed anything from your logic.

Comment: PLease could you look into it. Not sure why but its showing a small difference in the results with the new dataset. I have created  a new thread incase if you can't see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864982/how-to-take-difference-between-two-value-in-this-dataset-for-every-30-min-window

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a 30-minutes window difference for each item's observation, you can achieve it using self join. This function works for my case, so I hope it'll help:

```
def get_lagged_df(df: pd.DataFrame,
              id_col: str ='id',
              time_col: str = 'time',
              val_col: str = 'val',
              display_na_rows: bool = True) -> pd.DataFrame:

# Self join based on the ID
joined_df = pd.merge(df, df, on = id_col, suffixes = ('_end', '_start'))

# Keep only the rows where end time is above the start time
joined_df = joined_df[joined_df[f'{time_col}_end'] > joined_df[f'{time_col}_start']]

# Lambda function for getting differences between end time and start time in minutes
lambda_func = lambda row: int((pd.to_datetime(row[f'{time_col}_end']) - pd.to_datetime(row[f'{time_col}_start']))
                              .seconds / 60)

# Get the time differences in minutes between end time and start time
joined_df[f'{time_col}_difference'] = joined_df.apply(lambda_func, axis = 1)

# Kepp only the rows where the time difference is 30 minutes -> 30 min. window
joined_df = joined_df[joined_df[f'{time_col}_difference'] == 30]

# Get the difference between the first observation and last observation of 30 min. window
joined_df[f'{val_col}_difference'] = joined_df[f'{val_col}_end'] - joined_df[f'{val_col}_start']


# Appending N/A rows (i.e., rows which don't have any start times, hence no time and val differences)
if display_na_rows:
    df_w_na_rows = df.rename(columns = {f'{val_col}': f'{val_col}_end', f'{time_col}':f'{time_col}_end'})

    joined_df = pd.merge(df_w_na_rows,
                         joined_df.drop(f'{val_col}_end', axis = 1),
                         on = [id_col, f'{time_col}_end'],
                         how = 'left',
                        )

# Adjusting columns' and rows' orders
joined_df = (joined_df[[id_col, f'{time_col}_start', f'{time_col}_end', f'{time_col}_difference',
                        f'{val_col}_start', f'{val_col}_end', f'{val_col}_difference']]
             .sort_values(by=[id_col, f'{time_col}_end'])
             .reset_index(drop = True)
            )


return joined_df
```

Assume that you have this data in the following format:

| id | val | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.638129 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 0.047401 | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 |
| 1 | 0.781685 | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 |
| 1 | 0.839184 | 2023-01-01 00:03:00 |
| 1 | 0.526894 | 2023-01-01 00:04:00 |
| .. | ........ | .................. |
| 3 | 0.370669 | 2023-01-01 00:56:00 |
| 3 | 0.565692 | 2023-01-01 00:57:00 |
| 3 | 0.121998 | 2023-01-01 00:58:00 |
| 3 | 0.872352 | 2023-01-01 00:59:00 |
| 3 | 0.624171 | 2023-01-02 01:00:00 |

Where values for ID 1 in timestamps 00:00 and 00:30 are as follows:

| id | val | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.638129 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 0.184684 | 2023-01-01 00:30:00 |

When applying the function without displaying the rows with missing values (i.e., rows with no start times, hence no differences as well), we get difference between the value at time $t$ and the value at time $t-30$ for each ID's observation:

```
get_lagged_df(df, display_na_rows = False)
```

| id | time_start | time_end | time_difference | val_start | val_end | val_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:30:00 | 30 | 0.638129 | 0.184684 | -0.453445 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | 2023-01-01 00:31:00 | 30 | 0.047401 | 0.613936 | 0.566535 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | 2023-01-01 00:32:00 | 30 | 0.781685 | 0.865400 | 0.083714 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:03:00 | 2023-01-01 00:33:00 | 30 | 0.839184 | 0.089480 | -0.749704 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:04:00 | 2023-01-01 00:34:00 | 30 | 0.526894 | 0.541837 | 0.014943 |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:26:00 | 2023-01-01 00:56:00 | 30 | 0.812442 | 0.370669 | -0.441773 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:27:00 | 2023-01-01 00:57:00 | 30 | 0.352933 | 0.565692 | 0.212759 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:28:00 | 2023-01-01 00:58:00 | 30 | 0.186111 | 0.121998 | -0.064113 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:29:00 | 2023-01-01 00:59:00 | 30 | 0.671967 | 0.872352 | 0.200385 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:30:00 | 2023-01-02 01:00:00 | 30 | 0.008082 | 0.624171 | 0.616090 |

If we want to keep the rows with no start times as well, just change the `display_na_rows` argument to `True`:

```
get_lagged_df(df, display_na_rows = True)
```

| id | time_start | time_end | time_difference | val_start | val_end | val_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaT | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | NaN | NaN | 0.638129 | NaN |
| 1 | NaT | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | NaN | NaN | 0.047401 | NaN |
| 1 | NaT | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | NaN | NaN | 0.781685 | NaN |
| 1 | NaT | 2023-01-01 00:03:00 | NaN | NaN | 0.839184 | NaN |
| 1 | NaT | 2023-01-01 00:04:00 | NaN | NaN | 0.526894 | NaN |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:26:00 | 2023-01-01 00:56:00 | 30.0 | 0.812442 | 0.370669 | -0.441773 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:27:00 | 2023-01-01 00:57:00 | 30.0 | 0.352933 | 0.565692 | 0.212759 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:28:00 | 2023-01-01 00:58:00 | 30.0 | 0.186111 | 0.121998 | -0.064113 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:29:00 | 2023-01-01 00:59:00 | 30.0 | 0.671967 | 0.872352 | 0.200385 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:30:00 | 2023-01-02 01:00:00 | 30.0 | 0.008082 | 0.624171 | 0.616090 |

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. In my expected result I would like to have the row value of the reference timestamp used to take the difference, here it is: 2023-07-28T13:30:15.0338704+09:08. So the row value of the AgentStatus, Item is to be retained and then the difference of last - first value from the 30 min window. How do I keep that ? Basically rejoin the result with the row value is what I want as the result.